# how to parse json result without array name in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to parse json result without array name. I tried differet methods but non of it works these are my code.
So please someone tell me how to parse json result without using array name

thanks in advance.

**My JSON**

```
[{"id":"710","name":"app","address":"k","gender":"h"}]
```

I'm trying to parse this JSON

```
{"employees":[{"id":"710","name":"app","address":"k","gender":"h"}]}
```

I expect it like this

```
private class CheckList extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main2Activity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();

        Main2Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        final JParserAdv jParser = new JParserAdv();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://afkdemo.glabsapps.com/insertwebservice.asmx/getData?id=710", "GET", null);
        return json;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        ArrayList<ITEM> data=new ArrayList<ITEM>();
        try {
            //need to insert array name here but json result I'm using is without array name.
            JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("arrayname");
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++) {
                ITEM d = new ITEM();
                d.item_rank = ((JSONObject) arr.get(i)).get("id").toString();
                d.item_name = ((JSONObject) arr.get(i)).get("name").toString();
                d.item_population = ((JSONObject) arr.get(i)).get("address").toString();
                data.add(d);
            }
            My_adapter adapter = new My_adapter(Main2Activity.this, data);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON that you're trying to parse. It'll be easier for us to answer then.
Thanks.

Comment: [{"id":"710","name":"app","address":"k","gender":"h"}] I'm trying to parse this JSON

{"employees":[{"id":"710","name":"app","address":"k","gender":"h"}]}
I expect it like this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the endpoint you are requesting returns a JSON structure that looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    id: "710",
    name: "app",
    address: "k",
    gender: "h"
  }
]
```

Since your root does not have an identifier, try returning an array as the root in your `doInBackground()` method.

```
private class CheckList extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... args) {
        final JParserAdv jParser = new JParserAdv();
        JSONArray json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://afkdemo.glabsapps.com/insertwebservice.asmx/getData?id=710", "GET", null);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray json) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the `JParseAdv` API looks like, but hopefully there is a way to get it to return an array as the root of your JSON structure.

Comment: there is no method like json.getAsJsonArray in my code

Comment: Oops. I thought you were using the GSON library. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is there any other way to parse without identifier

Comment: I updated my answer. Did you give that suggestion a try?

Comment: Don't know how to reutrn array as root in doInBackground () method.

Answer (score 0):

First get the Employees into an array.

Then get the object at index=0. That should do the trick!

E.g:

```
JSONArray employees = json.optJSONArray("employees");
JSONObject anEmployee = employees.optJSONObject(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The following code worked for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private RequestQueue queue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);
    Button buttonParse = findViewById(R.id.button_parse);

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    buttonParse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jsonParse();
        }
    });
}


private void jsonParse() {

    String url = "http://10.216.70.19:8080/restServices/webapi/services/getAGVStatusList"; //This is my Json url
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //weatherData.setText("Response is :- ");
            parseData(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textView.setText("Data Not Received");

        }
    });

    queue.add(request);
    super.onStart();
}

private void parseData(String response) {
    try {
        // Create JSOn Object
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i <jsonArray.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("batteryLevel")); //get the desired information from the Json object

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}